# SSRS Tablix filter to exclude data from 1 dataset if its not in dataset 2

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

I am working on an report which has two slightly different data-sets (dataset 1 and dataset2). There are multiple tables within the report. 
For the tablix that is using dataset 1, I would like to add a filter that would exclude deals from dataset 1 that are not in dataset 2. The common Id for these datasets would be Dealid.

What would this Filter expression look like? Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a filter in your Dataset 1 or the Tablix and use the below expressions.

[image]

In `Expression` entry box use:

```
=IIF(
Isnothing(
Lookup(Fields!DealID.Value,Fields!DealID.Value,Fields!DealID.Value,"DataSet2")),
"Exclude","Include"
)
```

For the `Value` entry box use:

```
="Include"
```

It will exclude the rows where `DealID` in dataset 1 aren't present in dataset 2.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: For ease of future maintenance and knowing what the filter is doing, you can just set the Value as `Include`, there is no need to use `="..."`

Comment: @iamdave , you won't know _what the filter is doing_ by just see Include in the Value text box. Also I prefer to use explicit SSRS expressions.